# Move All null columns (Columns with zero non-null values) to the extreme right of the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 100's of columns. For few of the columns, the value is always null. I want to move all such columns (columns with zero non-null values) to the extreme right so that when my users see the table, they will get to see the usable information first.

Eg : test_table

```
**column1 | column2 | column3 | column4**
   a      | null    | null    |     1  
   b      | null    | null    |     2  
   c      | null    | null    |     3
```

After insertion, I want to make the test_table as like the below table

```
**column1 | column4 | column2 | column3**
   a      |     1   | null    | null
   b      |     2   | null    | null
   c      |     3   | null    | null
```

Comment: Is it needed for MySQL or for PostgreSQL?

Comment: do you know what columns that always return null ??

Comment: Columns are accessed by *name*, not by *position*. In many ways, any representation of *positions* is misleading. And you certainly don't want *inserts* to change the *structure* of your table. This seems like something that will be resolved when *querying* the table.

Comment: I want it in postgresql @KuKeC

Comment: @punk73 These columns are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The order the columns show up is defined when you query the table.
If you want these columns to show at the right end of the result set, you need to re-order them within the SELECT portion of your query.

So to stick to your example, instead of having:

```
Select column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM test_table
```

You would have:

```
Select column1, column4, column2, column3 FROM test_table
```

I do not believe there's a way to do this dynamically, but since you know these columns will always have a null value you should feel pretty confident with this.

Answer (score 0):

use isnull and case statment
select distinct isnull(id,0) from Employee
select distinct case when id is null then 0 else id end as id from Employee